# Is it possible to set navigationitem.title from a view's NIB?

Tags: ios, xcode4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder

I am loading a new view from a NIB (initWithNibName) and then I am pushing it into navigation controller stack (pushViewController).

In order to have a proper "Back" button each view should have a title.
Unfortunately I didn't manage to find a way to set up View Title in the Interface Builder.

It can be done in run time:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationItem.title = @"MyTitle";  
}
```

But I didn't manage to do it in design time in the NIB.

Is there a way of doing it?

Thank you.

---

I just realised my question is not 100% correct.

In fact I am looking for a way to set ViewController's title via NIB.

And UIView in the NIB is different from the UIViewController (which got the title property I am trying to change).

So my question was ... about something different. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the root view controller's navigation item through the navigation controller item.  The root view controller's navigation item has the property title that you can access in IB.

maybe this picture helps (your basically clicking on the blue navigation bar to put focus on the navigation item):

[image]

Comment: I would also add that you should be aware that the view controller's title would also be used by the navigation controller if that's available. So for example in the root view controller's viewDidLoad, you could do self.title = @"root vc title"

Comment: As far as I can see you are editing MainVindow.xib but not ViewController.xib

Comment: I am looking for the way to setup different titles for different ViewControllers during design time so the main window's navigation item gets update automatically once the new view is pushed into navigation controller stack.

Comment: Yeah, I'm in MainWindow.xib because in that view the root view controller is an object of the navigation controller.  In the root view controller's own xib file, what you see is the root view controller's view, not the view controller object itself.  So I'm confident you can't set it from in there because you can't access the view controllers properties there.  (and now I'm realizing that's what you were asking to begin with- in the view controller's .xib versus from any of your nib files).  Anyway, hope the explanation in this comment helps.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. And thank you for the picture.
I am sorry for my confusing question.
I know what you are talking about. But I have more than one view. And I am talking about view's titles. 
Basically all I need is a way to set view title in the NIB.
(And then once that view is pushed into navigation controller stack the navigation item will use that title.)

Comment: In fact after reading all your texts and all my text I understand that the real question should be if I can set ViewController's title in the NIB.

But it looks like I confused everyone including myself. :)

Comment: funny how that works.  I've learned a bit from this too.  Good luck!