# Can I insert a UINavigationController and set the title above my nib instantiated UITabBarController in my appdelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, xcode4.6

I am trying to make an iPhone application that has an optional top level navigation controller.

Adding it is fine, but trying to set the title doesn't work, unless you try to add your own navigation item, at which point the app crashes with an 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' with reason: 'Cannot call pushNavigationItem:animated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.'

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    rootHasNavBar = NO; 

    if (window && viewController)
    {

        // Tab Controller is root:
        if (!rootHasNavBar)
        {
           window.rootViewController = viewController; // viewController:UITabBarController
           [window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }
        else
        {
          // Navigation controller  above UITabBarController
          UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
            window.rootViewController = navigationController;
         //Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot call pushNavigationItem:animated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.'

          UINavigationItem* item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"RentalPoint",nil)];
          [ navigationController.navigationBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:YES];

            navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
          [window makeKeyAndVisible];

        };


    }
```

How should I do that?  Or is there some technical reason why I can't do that?

Update: The people who suggested simply moving the assignment of a controller title and navigation item title in the controller's viewDidLoad were on to some internal (and highly unintuitive for new person) aspects of Cocoa architecture that were still quite unfamiliar to me.  On the outside looking at a framework like Cocoa that is huge, and complex and which doesn't let you browse the source code, this is the kind of mystery that I find most difficult.   In my other languages and tools, I can always read and step into the code, including my frameworks.  here, you can't, and so you gotta read, read, read, and thankfully there are LOTs of great documentation sources.

Comment: Could you explain how you declare and init rootHasNavBar?  How about viewController, is that in a nib/storyboard?  It's weird to me that the viewController might be the window's root vc, then it might also be getting assigned as the root vc of a new navigation controller.

Comment: The viewController is nib instantiated UITabBarController, and is the root controller  unless I need a UINavigationController above it.  The BOOL is read from prefs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the navigation title on the init of your UIViewController.

```
self.title = @"My Title";
self.navigationItem.title = @"Nav Title"; //note: this will show-up in the back button when you push a subsequent view
```

or if you really wanted to hard code it into the applicationDidFinishLaunching routine, you could just do:

```
viewController.title = @"My Title";
```

Comment: If my UIViewController is nib-instatiated I could set these up in Interface Builder without any code right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418511/is-it-possible-to-set-navigationitem-title-from-a-views-nib

Comment: Accepting this answer because it's what I found easiest to do.  Other answer also works.

Answer (score 1):

I figure that a tab bar controller as the root of a navigation controller is the more complex case, so I did that in IB, saving the simpler case for the code.  First, I did the following (all in IB):

1. created a new single view project
2. deleted the default vc and added a navigation vc
3. deleted the navigation vc's defaulted root (a table vc)
4. painted a tab bar controller and made that the root
5. inspected the tab bar controller's navigation item and set it's title to "Rental Point"

I think that gives my app the "optional case" you refer to with the tab bar controller surrounded by a navigation controller (you said "above it", but your code says "around it, with it as the root").

Now the simpler case is easier to achieve in appDidFinishLaunching, as follows ...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // if I don't want the optional case, if I just want a tab bar controller as 
    // my window's root, grab it from the navigation controller, and make it the window's
    // root (thereby abandoning the navigation controller)

    if (YES) {
        UINavigationController *navVC = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        self.window.rootViewController = [navVC.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I think that's my code's problem? I want it visually above, not necessarily with the other view inside it.

Comment: You're definitely building that navigation controller with the tab bar controller as the root, which is a little unusual.  In the case where you want the navigation controller "above" the default UI, what do you want to have as the nav controller's root?

Comment: I know what I want visually, and logically (to be able to use the navigation controller to go back to this home screen using a back button) but not sure what I should have as the app root controller.

Comment: So can we think of your app as basically a tabbed app, except under some circumstance you want to present a nav controller (on top, with none of the main app tabs visible).  that nav controller should do the normal drill down, but have a "back" button at the root level, and that back button should dismiss the nav controller and reveal the tab bar controller again???  (that's a mouthful.  if it's what you want, i think i know how to make that happen).